# AWS Cloudfront does not render S3 bucket on the domain alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have my static website content put on S3, it has been given public permission and if I visit

`http://subdomain.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` I see the HTML.

In the Certificate Manager, I have a valid certificate generated for `subdomain.mydomain.com`

Now is the turn of CloudFront,

- picked the correct AWS S3 bucket folder.
- bucked hosted in North Virginia
- Associated the subdomian certificate
- in document root filled the `index.html`
- other settings in place.

Once the site is deployed, I open `<cloudfront-random-string>.cloudfront.net`

This renders the Static Website as is.

Finally, I head to route53, in the A record I create an alias and insert the `<cloudfront-random-string>.cloudfront.net`

When I open the subdomain.mydomain.com it renders no response.

What could go wrong?

Comment: Have you added subdomain.mydomain.com as an alternate domain name to your CloudFront distribution?

Comment: not required, since I am mapping A records. This needs to be done, if you would like to go the CNAME route.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are getting a 403, but this article may help.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/

Alternatively, you could try creating a Cloudfront Origin Access Identity & give it permission to access your S3 bucket. This way you can keep your S3 bucket private too.

```
  WebsiteBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub ${DomainName}
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      Tags:
        - Key: Domain
          Value: !Ref DomainName

  CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: !Sub CloudFront OAI for ${DomainName}

  WebsiteBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref WebsiteBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - s3:GetObject
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !Join [ "", [ "arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref WebsiteBucket, "/*" ] ]
            Principal:
              CanonicalUser: !GetAtt CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity.S3CanonicalUserId

  WebsiteCloudFront:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    DependsOn:
      - WebsiteBucketPolicy
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Comment: Cloudfront Distribution pointing to S3 bucket
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !GetAtt WebsiteBucket.DomainName
            Id: S3Origin
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity:
                !Join [ "", [ "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/", !Ref CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity ] ]
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: 'http2'
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        Aliases:
          - !Ref DomainName
        CustomErrorResponses:
          - ErrorCode: 404
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
          Compress: true
          TargetOriginId: S3Origin
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: true
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        PriceClass: PriceClass_100
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !Ref AcmCertificateArn
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
```